# Schema.org microdata - Price value not showing in google searchresults

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org

We had tagged our Product Detail web page with the 'Product' microdata. We are trying to show the Price of the item when a particular product is searched for on Google.
We marked up the item's price with the "**www.Schema.org/Offers**" itemscope and the "**Price**" itemtype.

See the Rich snippets data for the web page that I am talking about below:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.com%2FProductDetail%2FTexas-Instruments%2FTL072%2F%3Fqs%3DE2%2FxqS9xjzrrJtzLbEfvqg%3D%3D

Notice that the **"Availability"** shows on the search result, but not the **"Price"**.
I remember the same page worked in the past(last year). Wondering if something had changed meanwhile on how Google decided to read the Microdata.

Can anyone please help? 
Thanks Y'all

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're missing the priceCurrency. Add this to your offers section

```
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
```

Thank you for this, btw. I was trying to get mine to show In Stock only, without a price. Your question led to my solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to the how you have your price property structured. 
Look at this example:
Using this url the price shows up as $199 and the price has itemprop="price"
http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/Office-Star-Professional-Air-Grid-Deluxe-Task-Chair/2605023/product.html

But your price varies based on qty.

You may need to create a default price that is displayed for Google (maybe an "as low as")
itemprop="$0.373"

Hope that helps.